# Jmeter - Copying files from one host to another host in

Tags: java, performance, groovy, jmeter, loadrunner

Running `jmeter` in master slave mode, so it is creating some file in all the slave machines. Now facing issue with copying fils from that slave machines to master machine.

```
Exp: master machine ssh username@123.45.67

Slaves ssh username@123.45.68 and username@123.45.69
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following test elements combination:

1. [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) - to invoke the copy request after the main test logic has been executed and the file exists for sure
2. [SSH SFTP](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-sftp) sampler to copy the file to the master machine. It is not a part of JMeter, you will need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

   [image]

   once done you will be able to copy files from slave nodes to master one as simple as:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri however i have tried your way, after this getting permission denied ans response code : sftpexception. Can you please help me if you have any idea.